# Animate.CSS - Add IE Support?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, animated

I am using [Animate.CSS](http://daneden.me/animate/) and I am using the "hinge" effect to have an image fall off the screen. Works great in *real* browsers but of course not in IE 9 or below. Is there a way to make this effect work with jQuery or javascript? Or will I have to add a jQuery transition to fade the image out?

Thanks!

Code:

**HTML**

```
<img id="animate" class="fear" src="/2012/images/september/fear-sign.png" />
```

**CSS**

```css
.fear{
     position:absolute;
     left:150px;
     top:0px;
}

#animate {
    -moz-animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
    -o-animation-delay: 5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
    animation-delay: 5s;
}
```

**JS**

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j('#animate').addClass('animated hinge');
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/FafAH/4/) I created showing the animation effect.

Comment: You should contact the devs in Github to report those issues, even though odds are not many people will spend time trouble-shooting CSS3 bugs with older versions of IE. I'd consider contacting them anyway.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - Will do, even though I detest IE it won't be going anywhere anytime soon unfortunately.

Comment: where is your animated and hinge classes in CSs

Comment: @refhat Check the animate.css in the fiddle Resources. @Lynda, same, web devs spend more time making stuff compatible with IE than actually developing new technologies. I guess either a feature detection or user agent sniffing will be appropriate to fade out the image. I remember spending a whole night trying to make IE<=8 support border-radius, the only close things I found were [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/) (which "enables" some CSS3 stuff on IE) and a lot of `.htc` files which are quite dirty work - fading it out would be much cleaner.

Comment: @Lynda: As Fabrico said, there is nothing better than CSS3 pie to try out.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - Thank you for the help. You also make me feel I'm not alone in issues I find. I usually assume the novice in me is the problem. YEAH! And not yeah! It would be nice if they put time into the developments. I will now try the IE conditional comments. Thank you.

Comment: And even with Pie, the extra supported features are [very few](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/). Pretty sure it'd be easier to code a new browser than to make CSS animations with CSS3 features and easing work in older versions of IE (except the very basic ones, without the CSS `translate` which `hinge` uses, could be mimic'ed with jQuery). No problem. `=]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not as smooth as the Animate.CSS Hinge effect I ended up using jQuery to make the image fall off the screen (well fall and fade out.)

I had help from CoreyRS and his answer and method can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233752/create-a-falling-div-that-works-in-ie#answer-12233902).