# Create a falling div (that works in IE)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my original question and code but per CoreyRS's comment let me add some detail. I want to create a div that falls own the page and disappears `like a rock falling through the air`. The catch is it must work in IE 9 and 8. I have found some CSS3 animations that work great in all *but* IE. Any help is appreciated. Please provide code examples.

*Original Question and Code*

I am attempting to use the slideDown animation in jQuery to animate a div. The idea is a div will show then slide down the page and then fade out. Preferably it would fade out while falling but I cannot even get the div to fall. Here is my code:

**JS:**

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(window).load(function() {
    $j('#loading').fadeOut('slow', function() { //fade out loading div
        $j("#content-wrap").fadeIn("slow", function() { // show content div
            setTimeout( function() { // delay slideDown effect
                $j('#animate').slideDown('slow', function() {
                    // script to fade out or hide animate div
                }, 2000 );
            });    
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="loading">
    <h2 class="textcenter">Loading...</h2>
    <img id="loading-image" class="center" src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
</div>
<div id="content-wrap" class="hide">
  <div id="animate">
    <img class="fear" src="/sign.png" />
      </div>
    <div class="img-center">
        <img class="feature-image" src="/Prairie-Grass.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong and I will take any advice that will create a falling div on the screen that fades out that *will* work in IE 9 and 8.

Comment: Prepare a fiddle so others can rectify where is the issue.

Comment: theres a difference between falling down the page and the slideDown function... do you want it to simply reveal itself from top to bottom, or actually fall down the page like a rock falling through the air?

Comment: @CoreyRS - Got it. I am looking for a rock falling through the air. I have found ways to do that using CSS3 but that does not work in IE. I need a solution that will work in IE.

Comment: ok cool. animating the css property in jquery should work. i'll knock up the code.

Comment: @CoreyRS - Thanks, any help is greatly appreciated with code as JS is not my strong suit. =>

Comment: what div or element is it that you wish to have fall down the page?

Comment: @CoreyRS - `<div id="animate">` I edited my question, I left the div out in my original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't tested but give this a go. You'll need to edit the width/height properties etc to your needs, and obviously don't use inline styling if you have a css stylesheet.

```
<style>
#animate {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:fixed;
    top:-100px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:50px;
    z-index:1;  
}
</style>

<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(window).load(function() {
    $j('#loading').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $j("#content-wrap").fadeIn("slow", function() {
            $j('#animate').delay(2000).animate({'top':'50%'}, 500);
            $j('#animate').delay(2000).fadeOut(500);   
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: It works with one hangup. The `setTimeout` is firing to quickly. I want it to wait for about 2 - 3 seconds. When I change the `500` it only changes the speed of the effect not the delay. How do I change the `setTimeout`?

Comment: edited code. try that, i set a 2 second (2000 milliseconds) delay.

Comment: may not have been an IE problem that time. edited code, try it now.

Comment: removed the use of settimeout and insert a delay. try that.

Comment: Okay...Okay...I am going to tell you straight up...SORRY! I had an IE conditional comment in my code that was over riding your script! I took that out and your code works without issue. I am using setTimeout vs delay. Thank you so much for your help!!!