# Animated text fade in fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div which has two text's that is Text1 and Text2. When the site loads Text1 should fade out and Text2 should be shown. something like modal popup with auto close.

```
<div class="WelcomeText">
<h1> Welome to my site</h1>
<h1>Company Name</h1>
</div>
```

I have google for 3 hours can anybody suggest me how to implement or any plugin is available to achieve this ? I am using bootstrap. Also I need to make it work upto IE 7

Update : i have come with a small solution http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNdYqbm once he issue is fixed will will be adding css animation to it. I need a help where once first text disappears second text should stay? Could any body fix this.

Comment: I have a layout but i am looking a way to implement this. Any suggestions ?

Comment: there are jquery functions like `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` which you can use on `$(document).ready() function`

Comment: [Do you really need ie7 support?](http://www.theie7countdown.com/). As a side note: [bootstrap doesn't even support ie7](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/). *On Windows, we support Internet Explorer 8-11. More specific support information is provided below.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want animation based on css3, there are a lot of frameworks, but in my opinion, you can see [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) in here for references.

Unfortunately, I don't think animation based on css3 can work in IE7

Comment: This doesn't work in [ie 9 or below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233376/animate-css-add-ie-support)

Comment: Yea So i have decided to make it work above IE 8 at-least http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNdYqbm But i think we cannot add effect like animate.css through jquery ?